# Step into .NET source code not working for MVC4

Tags: .net, visual-studio, open-source, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following the instructions on this blog post for ["Stepping into ASP.NET MVC source code with Visual Studio debugger"](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/04/stepping-into-asp-net-mvc-source-code-with-visual-studio-debugger.aspx) but I can't get it to work for MVC 4.0.

I don't get the EULA prompt, nor does it appear to have found the symbols for MVC because they are still grey in the stack.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the reference source site:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

MVC4 is not currently provided by the source server.

For now, if you want to debug into it, you'll have to download the source and compile it yourself.

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Bummer. I have looked into debugging against MVC4 I built myself but its so complicated I gave up :(

Comment: I have tried following Steve Sanderson's instructions but I get various errors ('Metadata file ...could not be found') when I try to build http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/